# How to call processing page via web service

Tags: web-services, acumatica

I have a processing page and I want to run function process all via web service (add web reference into my C# window form app). My code below:

```
var context = new ModuleABCService.Screen() // limk web services: http://localhost:8686/soap/DMSBL009.asmx
            {
               CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
               AllowAutoRedirect = true,
               EnableDecompression = true,
               Timeout = 60000
             };
var loginResult = context.Login(string.Format("{0}@{1}", val.UserName, company), val.Password);
if (loginResult.Code != ErrorCode.OK)
{
   throw new Exception(string.Format("Can not login {0}", company));
}
Content content = context.GetSchema();
context.Clear();
context.Submit(
              new Command[] 
                          { 
                               content.Actions.ProcessAll
                          }
          );
```

And I got an exception message: 
**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExceptio:n Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXUndefinedCompanyException: Unable determine proper company id for the request. at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.getCompanyID(String tableName, companySetting& setting) in c:\Builders\4_10-2014_4_28-21_21_17-Full\Scripts\BuildTemp\NetTools\PX.Data\Database\Common\DbProviderBaseCompanies.cs:line 471...**

Have you ever got this error before? Could you please give me any suggestion? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out, because Acumatica's license

Comment: are you saying the web services don't work in trial mode?  I am running into the same issue but for the contract-based API