# How to call process specific item via web service

Tags: acumatica

I read this thread [How to call processing page via web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985100/how-to-call-processing-page-via-web-service) and know how to call process all via web services. But, i want to process one or some records. I dont know how to do that.

Please help me. Sorry, my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I still would like to suggest do not use processing screen for your operation, because you can do absolutely the same though original screen.

Answer (score -1):

The same approach, but you need to mark records before processing. 
From my standpoint it looks not really straight, maybe you shouldn't use processing screens via web services.

Comment: I use process page because i must create Sales Order and complete it (Invoice is released).